# If column has an specified value display row header

Tags: excel, if-statement, reference, display

example: Table Formatted (2 Sheets, 1st:Warehouse Storage, 2nd Warehouse Locations)

```
      A ..........J       
1    Job Name     Location
2    J. Doe       10-1, 10-5, 11-3
3    J. Smith     8-6, 8-7
```

Top row is Headers

I want to reference sheet one to show on sheet 2 if Location=10-4 it will show everything in J that has 10-4 in the body

Comment: what technology stack?

Comment: i do not understand that question, I am working in Excel.